# Como fazer requisições de parâmetros dentro no Java

Tags: java

Boa noite galera! Estou querendo desenvolver um programa para meu trabalho que vai facilitar muito pra fazer o que minha chefe pediu. O problema é que empaquei numa parte do codigo. Ja pesquisei na internet mas nao consegui passar de level. Alguem me ajuda por favor?

O problema em si: Quero fazer uma requisição dentro do Java.Net.Http mas nao sei como pedir os parametros dentro do codigo response.body. Em outras liguagens eu usaria o "[]", mas nessa isso nao funciona. O nome de parametro json que preciso é 'phone'

Agradeço desde já a todo mundo. Muito obrigado de verdade.

```
    CLASSE APISocio.java

package info.theocastro.linkedinphoneextractor;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;

public class APISocio {
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://rapidapi.p.rapidapi.com/cnpj/11754156000265"))
            .header("x-rapidapi-key", "cf2558ca2dmsh3540bbcccf44852p166e0ejsn4cb6bd56b328")
            .header("x-rapidapi-host", "consulta-empresa-cnpj-e-socios.p.rapidapi.com")
            .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
            .build();

}




     CLASSE APIEmpresa.java
package info.theocastro.linkedinphoneextractor;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;

public class APIEmpresa {
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://rapidapi.p.rapidapi.com/empresa/CYTH%20CAR%20COMERCIO%20DE%20VEICULOS%20EIRELI"))
            .header("x-rapidapi-key", "cf2558ca2dmsh3540bbcccf44852p166e0ejsn4cb6bd56b328")
            .header("x-rapidapi-host", "consulta-empresa-cnpj-e-socios.p.rapidapi.com")
            .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
            .build();
    
}




   CLASSE Principal.java

package info.theocastro.linkedinphoneextractor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

public class Principal{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        APIEmpresa apiEmpresa = new APIEmpresa();
        APISocio apiSocio = new APISocio();
                
        HttpResponse<String> responseEmpresa = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(apiEmpresa.request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        //System.out.println(responseEmpresa.body());
        
        HttpResponse<String> responseSocio = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(apiSocio.request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(responseSocio.body());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

O corpo (body) da resposta HTTP costuma ser tratado pela biblioteca como uma string, não necessariamente de um JSON, poderia ser de um XML por exemplo, de repente poderia até ser um dado binário (não-textual). Se souber que é um JSON (tem um item do cabeçalho que diz isso) você pode tratar com uma biblioteca para JSON como por exemplo a org.json.

Essa biblioteca tem que ser adicionada ao seu projeto, pois ela não faz parte da biblioteca-padrão do Java.

Comment: Entendi. Mas voce sabe entao como posso mandar puxar a variavel da api chamada 'phone'?

Comment: Por exemplo, com a biblioteca org.json você cria um `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.getBody())` e pega o campo por exemplo `String phone = obj.getString("phone")`. É questão de pesquisar como fazer exatamente.

Comment: Editei minha resposta informando que é uma biblioteca externa ao seu projeto.